# How to create a matrix using predetermined row, column, and value numbers in a string Java

Tags: java, string, loops, matrix, bufferedreader

I am stuck and need helpful input with my beginner code. I have a text file that contains:

```
{001 012 023 034 045 056 067 078 089 102 113 124 135 146 157 168 179 181 203 214 225 236 247 258 269 271 282 304 315 326 337 348 359 361 372 383 405 416 427 438 449 451 462 473 484 506 517 528 539 541 552 563 574 585 607 618 629 631 642 653 664 675 686 708 719 721 732 743 754 765 776 787 809 811 822 833 844 855 866 877 888}
```

Each triplet corresponds to the X and Y axis for the first two numbers and the value to put in this index is the third one.

**Step 1)** I buffered in the text and removed spaces to isolate each value(X,Y,Z) in its own string to ease use further out.

**Step 2)** I convert a specific character in each string to INT giving me 3 values I can then insert manually in my 9X9 matrix.

**Step 3)** For now I can manually select the index and populate one value in the matrix(in this example, in the code I selected index 8), I need to do this for all values in a loop but can't seem to figure out how to go forward with this.

Code:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class readBuffer {

    static void theBuffer() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("D://Documents/-/DOCS/School/Prog/game1.txt");

        String xString = ""; //three strings used for the coordinates
        String yString = "";
        String zString = "";
        int[][] tab = new int[9][9]; //9X9 matrix created

        try (
            //read file
            FileReader aFile = new FileReader(file);
            //
            BufferedReader theBuffer = new BufferedReader(aFile);
        ) {
            //Conversion to a String of characters
            String string = theBuffer.readLine();
            //removes spaces in the string
            string = string.replaceAll("\\s", "");

            //Loop that generates the  X,Y,Z coord and value strings
            //Row X (1st value in the triplet)
            for (int i = 0, n = string.length(); i < n; i++) {
                if ((i + 2) % 3 == 2)
                    xString += (string.charAt(i));

            }

            //Column Y (2nd value in the triplet)   
            for (int i = 0, n = string.length(); i < n; i++) {
                if ((i + 1) % 3 == 2)
                    yString += (string.charAt(i));
            }
            //Value Z (3rd value in the triplet)
            for (int i = 0, n = string.length(); i < n; i++) {
                if (i % 3 == 2)
                    zString += (string.charAt(i));
            }

            //Visualization for testing

            System.out.println("Row #:" + xString);
            System.out.println("Col #:" + yString);
            System.out.println("Num #:" + zString);


            int x = Character.getNumericValue(xString.charAt(8)); //Convert specific char to an INT
            int y = Character.getNumericValue(yString.charAt(8)); //Convert specific char to an INT
            int z = Character.getNumericValue(zString.charAt(8)); //Convert specific char to an INT

            //Visualization for testing

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("//Converted INT numbers//");
            System.out.println("Row #:" + x);
            System.out.println("Col #:" + y);
            System.out.println("Num #:" + z);

            //Loop that generates then 9X9 matrix
            tab[x][y] = z;
            System.out.println("");
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                    System.out.print(tab[i][j] + " ");
                System.out.println();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        theBuffer();
    }
}
```

[Image of console Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqJAd.png)

Need to fill this out and that is where I need advice.

Comment: You only assign value to matrix in one place, `tab[x][y] = z;`, and that is not inside a loop, so of course only one cell will get assigned. Try adding a loop.

Comment: Yes exactly, this is the part I need help with. How to iterate the charAt of the three converted ints to the tab[x][y] = z so I can populate the whole matrix.

Comment: *"How to iterate"* Well, with a `for` loop! ‍♂️ You're already doing it over `string`, so why can't you do it similarly over `xString`? And since `xString`, `yString`, and `zString` are the same size, you can extract from all 3 inside that one loop. Though, why you're separating them, when you need the together, is baffling to me. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67111612/5221149) for simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should just iterate the "triplets" and extract the 3 digits.

```java
static int[][] parseMatrix(String values) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[9][9];
    for (String triplet : values.split(" ")) {
        int row = Character.digit(triplet.charAt(0), 10);
        int col = Character.digit(triplet.charAt(1), 10);
        int val = Character.digit(triplet.charAt(2), 10);
        matrix[row][col] = val;
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

*Test*

```java
int[][] matrix = parseMatrix("001 012 023 034 045 056 067 078 089" +
                            " 102 113 124 135 146 157 168 179 181" +
                            " 203 214 225 236 247 258 269 271 282" +
                            " 304 315 326 337 348 359 361 372 383" +
                            " 405 416 427 438 449 451 462 473 484" +
                            " 506 517 528 539 541 552 563 574 585" +
                            " 607 618 629 631 642 653 664 675 686" +
                            " 708 719 721 732 743 754 765 776 787" +
                            " 809 811 822 833 844 855 866 877 888");
for (int[] row : matrix) {
    for (int value : row)
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 
6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: At first was looking how to do exactly what you proposed with the triplets and couldn<t figure it out, many thanks for this answer! I still have a long way to go.